# 2 binding, same port, different IP Addresses

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, windows-services, wcf-binding

I was trying port sharing and it don't work for me.

On one server I have 2 cards with different IP 192.168.101.2 and 192.168.100.1.
Client A have connection to server only by 192.168.101.2.
Client B have connection to server only by 192.168.100.1.
That's why I need to start the same service on the same port but different IP.

```
internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }

    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.PortSharingEnabled = true;
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service_WCF));


    ushort salt1 = (ushort)new Random().Next();
    string address1 = String.Format("net.tcp://192.168.100.1:8733/test/{0}", salt1);
    myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Interface_WCF), binding, address1);

    ushort salt2 = (ushort)new Random().Next();
    string address2 = String.Format("net.tcp://192.168.101.2:8733/test/{0}", salt2);

    myServiceHost.Open();
}
```

I still get exception when starting service:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at 'net.tcp://192.168.101.2:8733/test/27222' with contract(s) '"Interface_WCF"' is unable to open its IChannelListener. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A registration already exists for URI 'net.tcp://192.168.101.2:8733/test/27222'.

**EDIT 1: Meta data problem**
After EZI comment I changed IP to net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8733/test

Now i need to push metadata so:

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = false;
smb.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

var mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexBinding, "mex");
```

but at starting service:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

**EDIT 2: Meta data problem - resolved**

Delete line:

```
binding.PortSharingEnabled = true;
```

I don't know why but i can't add 2 endpoints when it is enabled.

Here is my final code:

```
internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }

    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8733/test");

    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service_WCF), baseAddress);
    myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Interface_WCF), binding, baseAddress);

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = false;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    var mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();

    myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexBinding, "mex");

    myServiceHost.Open();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
        myServiceHost = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: One endpoint is enough `net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8733/test`

Comment: Thanks! But what if I have 4 different IP and I need to use only 2? Going forward there is a problem with meta data. Check my Edit 1.